# Can't persist emojis with mysql and hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, unicode

I have actually found this problem multiple times on Stackoverflow, but the solutions would not help me.

I have a chat module in my android app and want to persist the messages in my server db, which works fine until special characters like emojis appear.

```
ERROR: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x81' for column 'message' at row 1
...
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x81' for column 'message' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1084)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4232)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4164)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2838)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2334)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2262)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2246)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
... 23 more
```

My environment is:

```
-Mysql 5.6
-Tomcat 8.0.8
-Hibernate 4.3.5
-JDK 1.8.0_05
```

This is the used table with the column in question, 'message':

[image: table properties]

These are my properties in the persistence.xml (version 2.1):

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gamedb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="*********" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="**************" />

<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8" />
```

Now I tried the following solutions without effect:

```
-Change datatype of 'message' from varchar to longtext
-Change collation of 'message' to utf8mb4
-Change collation of table to utf8mb4
-Append url with "?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
-Set character-set-server of mysql to utf8mb4
```

I think the emoji is correctly transmitted to the server, before it persists the message it broadcasts it back to the app and it gets correctly displayed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After not receiving further answers to my comments I found an alternative solution: Base64.

Instead of teaching my DB to understand utf8mb4 I encode all critical messages to Base64 before storing them and decode them when retrieving them from the database.

Pro:
- Works great
- Libraries are already given for java and android

Contra:
- Base64 strings take up more space than the pure utf8mb4 strings (33%-36% more)
- May cost some performance encoding and decoding

Comment: yeah well gl searching or ordering

Answer (score 7):

I once had the same problem. I don't know a pretty solution but this had worked for me.

After I created the Session object I changed the connection collation by hand:

```
s.doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException
    {
        try(Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
            stmt.executeQuery("SET NAMES utf8mb4");
        }

        return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are using **hibernate** with **c3p0**, you can use c3p0 config **connectionCustomizerClassName** whitch you can set to a class doing work with connections c3p0 got.

example:

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.connectionCustomizerClassName">com.hzmoyan.newlyappserver.db.C3p0UseUtf8mb4</property>
```

C3p0UseUtf8mb4 class

```
public class C3p0UseUtf8mb4 extends  AbstractConnectionCustomizer{
     @Override
    public void onAcquire(Connection c, String parentDataSourceIdentityToken)
        throws Exception {
        super.onAcquire(c, parentDataSourceIdentityToken);
        try(Statement stmt = c.createStatement()) {
            stmt.executeQuery("SET NAMES utf8mb4");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to [use `utf8mb4` rather than `utf8` in MySQL](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4). The blog post I linked to explains how to do just that.

Comment: I followed every step but the part in step 5 with 'SET NAMES', because I use a javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory instead of the hibernate alternative, thus not using any statement queries.
I changed the url so that it has utf8mb4 instead of utf8 and added hibernate.connection.CharSet with utf8mb4, but the .characterEncoding Value cannot be changed from utf8 to utf8mb4 without errors.
Do I have to use the Hibernate session management for this instead of what I have now?

Comment: Probably good to improve this by pulling in relevant information from that blog post, in case it goes 404.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a nice little hack to get this to work without having to add any code. If you set the validation query to be SET NAMES utf8mb4 then it will execute this when it gets the connection, therefore setting the parameter each time a new connection is retrieved. You also need test on borrow to make this work.

Note I have found that this can sometimes take a few seconds to work after a restart so could have failures if you have records waiting to be processed on startup

So in your application.properties you would add something like

```
datasource.test-on-borrow=true
datasource.validation-query=SET NAMES utf8mb4
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by providing the following in my connection URL;

**useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8**

Example;

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to modify hibernate configuration as

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8mb4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If your datasource is `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` you can set `connectionInitSqls` parameter

```
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}"
          p:testOnBorrow="true"
          p:maxActive="1000"
          p:testWhileIdle="true"
          p:validationQuery="SELECT 1"
          p:validationQueryTimeout="5">

        <property name="connectionInitSqls">
            <list>
                <value>SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'</value>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>
```